# Ubuntu Mate 22.04 (Jammy) crashes randomly when clicking web links on Brave, Firefox and Chrome

Tags: crash, mate

I used Mate for quite a long time without this issue. Recently Ubuntu started to crashes often with Brave, Chrome and Firefox. So it is obviously not a browser issue. I red on different forums, that many other Mate users had this crashing problem. It happens most of the time when I click a web link; then I see a black page and Ubuntu goes to the login password page and I have to start a new session. I didn't change any hardware on my laptop and the fact that many people with different hardware setups have the same problem, points to Ubuntu being the cause. Any idea of what is causing these crashes?

Comment: I don't understand your situation and logic; what crashes?  Is the system crashing? (ie. lock up & you need to SysRq to reboot to regain control? or not even sysrq works and it's thus kernel panic related?), is your session just ending (ie. you're returned to the DM and need to login again, ie. system isn't crashing, just the session/GUI is?) Why is not the browsers given you mention them? Have you explored .crash files? system logs? I'm not aware of any such other reports; but if you have found bug reports please provide the link. When did it first occur? what upgrades were added before then?

Comment: Please add the browser (firefox, chrome, chromium, brave,  edge, ...) you are using to the question.

Comment: Loook at `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -ex` to see the system logs leading up to the crash. Read `man journalctl`. Also, `journalctl  --list-boots`. This is slow, but it's so handy that I have a `cron` job, scheduled for `@reboot` that stores the results in a file for later reference.

Comment: Guiverc: It is my session ending and I need to login again. Where are the crash files? I found similar behaviour on Reddit and Ubuntu Mate forum: (Browser consistently crashes MATE desktop session: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/browser-consistently-crashes-mate-desktop-session/25855) also on Reddit. It started this week and no upgrade was made.

Comment: waltinator: 1) First command: The journal stopped 2) Second command gives journal instructions. Since the journal stopped, instructions don't have much utility. 3) (list - boots) didn't give any answer.

Comment: Crash files are found in `/var/crash`; you can submit them using `ubuntu-bug` and just read them using `view` or other equivalent command (*the start of the file is pretty easy to read, alas when it gets further down they can switch to a textual version of a dump-file thus tools are needed to make them easier to read; or if submitted online using the prior command I find them easier to read on launchpad*).